# How to get elapsed time between PHP date and current JS date

Tags: javascript, php, date

I want to calculate the elapsed time between two dates. The start date is calculated using PHP and is stored in mySQL as a datetime field. Then on my webpage I want to use JS to show the time elapsed between my database datetime and the current datetime.

When I get the date in seconds in JS it does not include British summer time. But the database version does. How do I get or calculate the number of  seconds since epoch including summer time?

```
var start = document.getElementById('unix_start').value; 
display_elapsed = document.getElementById('elapsed');

//var now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // returns UTC seconds

var nowm = new Date();
var now = Math.floor(nowm.getTime() / 1000); // also UTC seconds

var elapsed = now - start;
var h = Math.floor(elapsed / 3600);
var m = Math.floor((elapsed - (h*3600)) / 60);
// plus some formatting logic...for leading zeros

display_elapsed.value =  h+':'+m;
```

I want the web page to show e.g. 1.00 hours elapsed. Instead it always starts negative as -1.00 and only goes positive after an hour.

Comment: What is the value of *start*? mySQL returns datetime fields in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', it seems that's not the format of the value of *unix_start*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I have now discovered the getTimezoneOffset() function. So I used the following:

```
var start = document.getElementById('unix_start').value; 
var display_elapsed = document.getElementById('elapsed');
var nowm = new Date();
var offset=nowm.getTimezoneOffset() * 60; // convert to seconds
var now = Math.floor(nowm.getTime() / 1000) - offset;
var start = document.getElementById('unix_start').value;
var elapsed = now - start;
var h = Math.floor(elapsed / 3600);
var m = Math.floor((elapsed - (h*3600)) / 60);
// plus some formatting logic...for leading zeros
display_elapsed.value =  h+':'+m;
```

Comment: Date.now() returns an ECMAScript time value in milliseconds. UNIX time values are (usually) seconds from the same epoch. Both are UTC. So to get the difference in seconds, just to `Date.now() / 1000 - UNIX_time`.